# How can I find original or past filenames if I did not created a security copy or a point of restoration?

Tags: backup, restore, rename, filenames

I used a program for changing file names in a masive way, that program I used was "reNamer", but now I'd like to return all the original names because I believe I made an error when I tried to change the names of my files.

In addition I don't have to recover a deleted file or document, I have the originals but just to finish I moved those carpets where my files were in.

I moved them in different zones of my computer, these folders were moving between my desktop and in my (D) disk. I think it affects to find original file names.

Maybe someone can help me with a recommendation of an app or something that can help me.

PD: I never created a point of restoration or a backup.

Comment: Are these just data files or are they system files?

Answer (score 2):

Take this as a learning moment. To backup.

ESPECIALLY before undertaking system-wide changes.

I'd say you're out of luck.
That kind of data is not preserved at a file level, so unless the software you used offers logs, or a "restore" function...you're unlikely to be able to revert..

Comment: Welcome to SU.  Please moderate your language as something suitable for work environments.

Comment: Thanks davidgo. Not sure what work environment you're in, or referring to, the unedited language is certainly suitable in mine.  And I generally don't post anything on the net that I wouldn't say to my nan. But I guess some nans are different from others. I will take it under advisement.  

And there is a vast difference between "changes" and "f*ckery"